# How to avoid name conflict in case of macros for assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I want to declare the following macro in my `common.h` file:

```
.macro HEX_NIBBLE reg
    //LOCAL letter, end
    cmp $10, \reg
    jae letter
    add $'0, \reg
    jmp end
letter:
    /* 0x37 == 'A' - 10 */
    add $0x37, \reg
end:
.endm
```

Whenever I call the above core at more than one place in my `main.S` code, I get the following errors :

```
$ as --32 -o main.o main.S -g
main.S: Assembler messages:
main.S:17: Error: symbol `letter' is already defined
main.S:17: Error: symbol `end' is already defined
main.S:17: Error: symbol `letter' is already defined
main.S:17: Error: symbol `end' is already defined
main.S:17: Error: symbol `letter' is already defined
main.S:17: Error: symbol `end' is already defined
```

I want to use only GNU assembler (GAS), no GCC. How can I avoid these errors? Is there any assembly directive for this situation?

`main.S` can be taken anything for this examples, say below code :

```
.include "common.h"
BEGIN
    HEX_NIBBLE %ax
    HEX_NIBBLE %ax
    HEX_NIBBLE %ax
    HEX_NIBBLE %ax
    hlt
```

Comment: Use [local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1) or [macro unique labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html#index-number-of-macros-executed)

Comment: re: hex: you might be interested in [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53823756)